# Declaring 72,000 Variables

Tags: c#

TL:DR
A game I play has a ScriptableObject asset containing 72,000 variables, decompiling the UnityProject shows me this asset's 72,000 variables, each with a declared value, building my assumption they were individually set. This seems highly impractical, therefore there must be a much smaller # of formulas that declare the entirety of the asset's variables within scripts, and the decompiler is just showing me the final-product once everything is ran.

The issue with this assumption is, when I use dnSpy (.Net Decompiler) to search for all known references to each variable, it finds ZERO declarations for them within the project, leading me to believe the only way for them to be "declared" without being declared within scripts is, if they were set by hand inside the asset.

**My question would be**, a*re there other ways these variables could've been declared that would, not be within scripts (hence zero references) & without hand-setting (impractical).*

References:

- [ScriptableObject-Class](https://pastebin.com/zAhcaSwV)
- [Decompiled-ScriptableObject-Asset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDtqQ.jpg)

TL:DR end

**Full:**

Basically, the game contains 30 "Tiers/Floors", each floor can be leveled 1-300, each level contains 8x variables. Doing the math, we get 72,000 declarable variables.

Using a program that extracts Unity-Assets from a compiled apk (Again, strictly for educational purposes) I found the ScriptableObject used to set these values.
When viewed by the program, it contains all 72,000 variables each with a declared value.

I thought this seemed odd since, if they were pre-declared by-hand, balancing mechanics (like the ratio of cost:benifit) would prove beyond difficult.

What would make sense is, though the program displays all 72,000 variables, maybe it is only showing me them because inside the code, there are declared formulas (for each tier) determining how to calculate each of the 8 variables per level.
Something like, 
for tier 1's variable 'cost':

```
//1 formula declares 300 'cost' variables for tier-1 only
[tier-1][level].cost = level*1.15
```

This would mean only declaring 240-Individual formulas and seems like the obvious and most practical way to declare a large set of variables. The issue is, upon inspecting the scripts via dnSpy (a .NET decompiler) I tried to "analyze" the variables to locate **ALL** references to it within the project; I only found 2 references (for each var) that just read the variable, and zero references that declare it in anyway (I should be seeing formulas that declare these values if they existed in the current context).

I should probably note, the developers were a team consisting of "10-50" employees from what i've gathered. Maybe 72,000 variables doesn't seem like such a hard task with a team of this size?

I would like to know if there is another way these variables can be set, that fits with the context of, when searching for references of the variables, I receive zero results declaring the variables & assuming the variables were not set individually by hand.

Comment: Sounds like some obfuscation has truend the arrays into seemingly seperate variables. Obfuscation is there specifically to make reverse engineering like this hard. So it is propably doing it's job.

Comment: The screenshot looks like a yaml array to me.

Comment: Take a look at the references, nothing appears obfuscated. 72,000 is the correct # of variables I expected there to be given the context.

Comment: I would have thought all your levels wouldn't be instanced at the same time.  Having 72,000 variables in an application is fine when only 8 of those variables are instanced (actually taking up physical memory) at any particular time.

Comment: What you see there could possibly be deserialized data. If the fields of those `Param` object instances have been set using reflection or through some (binary) deserialization mechanism, it will be rather unlikely to find explicit assignments (setting) of those fields. The whole data is definitely not inputted by hand, but rather created by some script(s)/algorithm(s)/software (and possibly with some manual inputs and adjustments here and there) and then serialized/persisted in some way.

Comment: Decompiling can yield different results to the original source. But it could also be obfuscation as previously suggested.